# Can I use something other than 'self' in this PyQt Function?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am new to Python and PyQt. This function is not within a class, and is called by another function that is not self referencing. (I'm not sure if that's what you call it. What I mean is, none of the functions are of the type `function_name(self)`)

```
def openFileDialog():
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "/home/username/Pictures")
    print(filename)
```

What can I pass instead of `self`? I have tried `Dialog`, `none`, `parent=none`, but neither of those work.

Comment: Are you calling this function from a GUI tool, or is it a command line tool?

Comment: What do you mean by "neither of those work". And what do you want to accomplish by passing anything instead of self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parent` argument is just so the `QFileDialog` is correctly parented to a widget.  There are many reasons why you would want dialogs and windows to be correctly parented to each other.

- They inherit the styling and color palette of the parent.
- They will be created with a window position relative to the parent.
- The window manager for your OS will treat them as the same application (for example, on a taskbar or dock, both dialogs/windows will be grouped together).
- Unhandled events propagate up to the parent.

If you don't care about any of these things, you could just pass in `None`.

```
filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open File", "/home/username/Pictures")
```

Or, to be a little more versatile, give your function an optional `parent` argument

```
def openFileDialog(parent=None):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent, "Open File", "/home/username/Pictures")
    print(filename)
```

Comment: I understand.
I had tried 'none' and not 'None'. Silly errors!
Thank you so much, it worked. :)